# CSS: alter hover color based on another style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

The situation: We have an angular structure that builds a series of LI items in a UL, set to use css to mimic a dropdown list.

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="ddl_suppliersList">
      <li ng-click="clearSuppliersList()">
           <input type="checkbox" class="form-control input-sm" /><label>Unselect All</label>
      </li>
      <li ng-repeat="supplier in suppliers track by $index" ng-class="{highlightedRow: supplier.isSelected}" ng-click="supplierSelected($index)">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control input-sm" /><label ng-class="{highlightedRow: supplier.isSelected}">{{supplier.supplierPreferredName}}</label>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Stylesheet:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > label {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #333333;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > label:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > label:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #262626;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > input:checked ~ label,
.dropdown-menu > li > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > input:checked ~ label:focus,
.dropdown-menu > .active > label,
.dropdown-menu > .active > label:hover,
.dropdown-menu > .active > label:focus {
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #428bca;
}
```

(I think that's the relevant bit)

It displays as so:

[image]

The user can select many items - the css style "highlightedRow" is located in a separate style sheet from the one for the "dropdown-menu" styles

[image]

Stylesheet for "highlightedRow"

```
.highlightedRow {
  background-color: #0D82F5;
  color: white;
}
```

The problem is, that second company is selected, but the hover style hides it completely.

[image]

That's proving confusing for the users.

I believe a solution would be if the hover color for selections that have been selected could change to some other color to indicate that the item beneath is selected.  But I've no idea how to build it.

I suspect I can add another style to the LI items like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control input-sm" /><label ng-class="{highlightedRow: supplier.isSelected; hoverAlt: supplier.isSelected}">{{supplier.supplierPreferredName}}</label>
```

But I've not been able to nail down exactly what to call it, and where to place it so it overrides the existing hover color.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Just add the hover event to the selected row

Add this:

```
.highlightedRow:hover {
  background-color: #3c8ddd; /*Any color you want on the hover*/
}
```

Comment: That sure sounds like it'd work, but the hover for the dropdown list still takes precedence. If I comment out the line ".dropdown-menu > li > label:hover,"  above, the new hover color shows up. I tried reversing the order that the stylesheets rendered in the page just to see if it made a difference - didn't.

Comment: If all that you tried didn't helped, a quick solution would be using `background-color: #3c8ddd!important;`. But keep in mind it is not considered the best pratice.

Comment: Bingo!  I think there's a typo - further research shows that should be an exclamation point and not a colon, but it's working.  More details on the tool - https://www.developeracademy.io/css-important-rule-use-correctly/